# i am trying to make a simple chat app with flask_socketio and it doesn't work properly

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a simple chat app by using flask and flask_socketio and it works but the WebSocket upgrade doesn't happen and it gives me this error properly

> The WebSocket transport is not available, you must install a WebSocket server that is compatible with your async mode to enable it. See the documentation for details. (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)

and I saw many tutorials and ended with installing (gunicorn, gevent, eventlet) and updating the packages and the library but when I run the app it works and the message sent from the client to the server and broadcasting it again to all the client but the connection is not websocket it's pooling

**the server-side**

```
from flask import Flask, app, render_template, redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO



app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'test'
socketio = SocketIO(app)



@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('chat.html')


@socketio.on('message')
def message_func(data):

    socketio.send(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

**the client**

```
var socket = io('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
})

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    const br = document.createElement('br');
    p.innerHTML = data;
    document.querySelector('#panel').append(p);

})


document.querySelector('#send').onclick = () => {
    socket.send(document.querySelector('#userin').value)
}
```

Comment: What do you have in your virtualenv? Add the output of the `pip freeze` command to the question. Also indicate the command that you use to start the server.

Answer (score 1):

In the ["Deployment: Gunicorn Web Server"](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#gunicorn-web-server) documentation it says

> In the documentation of  When using gunicorn with the gevent worker
> and the WebSocket support provided by gevent-websocket, the command
> that starts the server must be changed to select a custom gevent web
> server that supports the WebSocket protocol. The modified command is:
>
> ```
> gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 module:app
> ```

For that to work you additionally need to install [gevent-websocket](https://pypi.org/project/gevent-websocket/).